# TomEE redirection issue https to http to https - Web application

Tags: http, https, redirect, apache-tomee

When I access my application using https://application.domain.net/ui, the request is getting redirected in a weird fashion.

Log:

```
    GET 302 Redirect (cached)   https://application.domain.net/ui
    GET 301 Redirect to: http://application.domain.net/ui/login.do
    GET 200 text/html   https://application.domain.net/ui/login.do
```

Application Server: TomEE 1.7.4 with SSL connector enabled.
Application: ear application

The application later brings the login page. But **why would the redirection happen from https to http then to https**

My TomEE conf/server.xml content with connector details:

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" xpoweredBy="false" server="Apache TomEE" />

    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" xpoweredBy="false"   server="Apache TomEE" />

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: Solution: The issue I mentioned in this post seem to be an issue with Rewrite valve. Loadbalancer rule should help add a trailing slash if user has not provided in the request.  Refer to https://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4316274.htm

Answer (score 1):

can be programmatic or configured in web.xml, you can enforce https by setting transport-guarantee to CONFIDENTIAL in web.xml.